# Alternative approach for ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am designing a form which has part expandable groups and part generic form elements. When we uncollapse the group, an individual form is displayed.

I have tried with ExpandableListView but there are too many files that needs to be created. We have four tabs and each should have its own expandable list. What could be the alternative way to handle this?

The view I am expecting looks something like this: (ofcourse we have four tabs and each should have this view).

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved my problem. You have to change the static values. I hope it works.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selectedItem);
            if (holder != null) {
                holder.expandButton.setSelected(false);
                holder.expandableLayout.collapse();

            }

            int position = getAdapterPosition();


            //dynamic Listview Height calculate start
            float scale = view.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;

            int hh = 0;
            try {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
                int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated


                View childView = listdetail.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listdetail);
                childView.measure(UNBOUNDED, UNBOUNDED);
                hh=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int scl = (int)(scale * (12f));
            scl = scl<=0?1:scl;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listdetail.getLayoutParams();
            if(hh<=0) {
                params.height = 10 * (listdetail.getAdapter().getCount()) * scl;
            }
            else {
                params.height = (int) (((scale<0f?1f:1f) *hh * (listdetail.getAdapter().getCount()))+10);
            }
            listdetail.setLayoutParams(params);

            //dynamic Listview Height calculate stop

            if (position == selectedItem) {
                selectedItem = UNSELECTED;
            } else {
                expandButton.setSelected(true);
                expandableLayout.expand();
                selectedItem = position;

            }
        }
```

Comment: The point is we cannot use ExpadableListView if we want to avoid creating multiple files. Trying to make sense of your code but couldn't understand how that fits in.